# process in Uniform Interface vs HTTP verbs

Tags: rest, http, http-verbs, uniform-interface

by considering the application of REST principles in the web.
i am doing a case study on REST and I have some doubt mostly on Uniform interface. 
I assumes that Uniform Interface has only one single PROCESS instead of HTTP verbs (e.g. get, post, put, delete, head, ...). Is there any potential consequences of this kind of process with conventional HTTP verbs?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any potential consequences of this kind of process with conventional HTTP verbs?

There are a few.

One consideration is safety.  In the RFC-7231, [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) is defined this way.

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are essentially read-only; i.e., the client does not request, and does not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of applying a safe method to a target resource.

So if PROCESS were a safe verb, like GET, you would have an analog of the read-only web.  The HTTP spec also defines HEAD and OPTIONS (which are optimized reads) and TRACE (a debugging tool); given that HTML has been an extremely successful hypermedia format without including support for these methods suggests that they aren't particularly critical of themselves.

A safe specification of PROCESS preserves all of the scaling benefits of REST.  But it's utility is limited - clients can consume content, but they can't *produce* any.

On the other hand, if PROCESS isn't safe, then a bunch of use cases can no longer be supported.  Prefetching content is no longer an option, because the components can no longer assume that invoking PROCESS has no side effects on the server.  Crawling is no longer an option, for the same reason.

It's probably worth noticing the mechanics of methods in the web -- it's the hypermedia format that describes which methods are appropriate for which links.  So you could potentially work around some of the issues by defining the restrictions on the method within the hypermedia format itself.  It's a different way of communicating the same information to any component that can consume the media type in question.

But there are at least two additional considerations.  First, that the information in the links can only be understood by components that know that media type.  On the web, most components are media type agnostic -- caching html looks exactly like caching json looks like caching jpeg.

Second, that the information in the links is only available on the outbound side.  REST means stateless - all of the information needed to process the request is contained within the request.  That implies that the request must include within it all of the information needed to handle a communication failure.

For instance, the http spec defines [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2).

> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same as the effect for a single such request.

This property is important for [intermediary components](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#tab_5_3) when they forward a request along an unreliable, and receive no response from the server.  We've got no way to know if a message is lost, or just slow, and we've got no way to distinguish the request message being lost from the response message being lost.

If the request includes the information that it is idempotent, then the intermediaries know that they can resend the message to the server, rather than reporting the error to the client.

Contrast this with correct handling of POST in http; since the POST request does not have an idempotent marker on it, the components do not know that a resending the message is going to have the desired effect (which is why web browsers typically display a warning if you try to POST a form twice).

Locking yourself into a single method give you a choice; do you want to support error recovery by intermediaries? or do you want the flexibility to support not-idempotent writes?

Comment: if I consider that a process consist several individual HTTP verb in the process ( instead of using one by one). what would be the consequence of that ? does it degrade "loose coupling" feature of uniform interface ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here - if you edit your question and clarify, I may be able to answer.